# Jquery ui tab issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using `jquery UI tabs` and want to know that , is it possible to point a div's id which is not present in

the `main tab div` container, means

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#outerdiv">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Tab 2</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="outerdiv">
        <p>Tab 3</p>
    </div>
```

I tried this but `div#outer` contents not opening when i click on **tab3**. How can i do this?

Comment: Without changing the source (of jquery ui tabs) or doing some hack  (moving the `outer` div using code) .... no

Comment: @ManseUK You don't need to edit the source of jquery ui tabs to get this to work, you can make use of the `load` method, but its still not very tidy..

Comment: @Curt +1 on your answer - but like you say - its untidy and would need to be modified for each different case ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the default jQuery plugin is looking `$(this).find("#outerdiv")` (where `this`=`#tabs`) which your element is not.

There are ways of getting this to work, but I think the neatest thing to do would be to move `#outerdiv` into `#tabs`.

If you insist on keeping the markup the same, you can make use of the `load` method like so:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
 load: function (event, ui) {
    switch (ui.index) {
       case 2:
           $("#tabs div").hide();
           $("#outerdiv").show();
           break;
    }
}
});
```

But I don't know how this will affect the rest of your tab panels. You'll probably have to add them all into this switch function.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the `div` using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) before initialising the tabs :

```
$("#outerdiv").appendTo("#tabs");
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/FACC8/)